# Lenovo Legion Y520 - Strange Fan speed Fluctatuion at low load with low temp

Tags: nvidia, sound, fan, temperature

- I have Lenovo Legion Y520 with ubuntu 20.04, with GTX1060 With Nvidia Driver 455.45.01 With Cuda 11.1 installed
- The Fan Speed Strangely Fluctuates from low speed (low sound) to high speed (high sound) at very low CPU load and The CPU temp would be around 40°C, This is the output of `sensors` is:

```
pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +42.5°C  

nvme-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +27.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +68.8°C)
                       (crit = +71.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +27.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +33.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          12.70 V
```

Is it a software bug or a hardware proplem or should I clean my Laptop?

Comment: I see no problems with those temps, but it never hurts to clean the dust out -- you might be surprised how much of it there is.

Comment: will those temps make the fan moves very fast (make a loud noise)? also the fan speed is fluctuating rapidly like there is a problem with its controller, the fan moves very fast for like 30 seconds, stops for 5 seconds, and move fast again

Comment: Check the temp from the nvidia-settings also.  Sounds like something's getting hot and a fan kicks in, cools it and stops, ... repeat.  Under load, maybe 70-80 degrees is normal, but 40 is nothing.

Comment: nvidia-settings says that the GPU temp is 39 degrees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following steps:

1. I cleaned the laptop
2. In `nvidia-setting -> PRIME Profiles`, I changed `NVIDIA (Performance Mode)` to `NVIDA On-Demand`
3. Restarted the laptop for changes to take effect.

And The laptop now is soundless with low fan speed.

### **Note**

I had to wait a few minutes after applying the solution for the laptop to cool down and the fans to rotate at low speed.